# How to add a title text input to an image field node form widget

Tags: 8, forms, files, media

If you have an image field widget in a Drupal node form you can automatically edit the image alt text in there, but is it also possible to add a title text field?

When I install the File Entity module I can add title text to images by editing them from admin/content/files but it doesn't make sense to tell clients to use this admin page to finish authoring their content.

Just to be clear, I don't want to have to make every image into a node, I just want to add form input fields to the image field widget so that the file entities can get a title text in the node form.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for the Paragraphs module

Comment: @Clive I don't think so, in Drupal 7 you can edit title fields by default, seems like this shouldn't require any additional modules to work.

Comment: Oh right, are you maybe just talking about selecting the _Enable title field_ option at e.g. /admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/node.article.field_image?

Comment: exactly, I just found out myself and came back here to answer myself. I was searching this option in the Manage form display tab but it's in the manage fields tab. thx.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the title field on your image field in the manage field tabs, at the bottom of the field form. for example at
example.comadmin/structure/types/manage/example_content_type/fields/node.example_content_type.field_example_field

Found the answer after landing here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2303765